# Why Callback function does not execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
function url()
{
    var companyName='ROCHESTER REGIONAL LIBRARY COUNCIL';
    var parts=companyName.split(" ");
    var newName="";
    for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
    {
        newName+=parts[i];
        newName+="+";
    }

    newName=newName.substring(0,newName.length-1);
    var url="http://www.brightscope.com/autocomplete/search-box/company/?q=";
    url+=newName;
    url+="&limit=15&timestamp=1388104659571";
    return url;
}

function getjsonn(callback)
{
    var urlv=url();
    $.ajax({
        url:urlv,
        success: callback
        });     
}

function callback(result)
{
    alert(result);
    document.getElementById('te').innerHTML=result;
}
```

I am sending an ajax request to get a Json response.
I think the return value of the request should be a Json Object which I process further.

Right now, it seems like the callback function doesn't run.
I tried to debug the code using firebug, in the console window there is a line shows a successful get request.

Thanks all your help. I forgot to add callback as parameter when I call getjsonn(),
I made some changes and this works on IE browser now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script> 

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>        </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function url()
{
    var companyName='ROCHESTER REGIONAL LIBRARY COUNCIL';
    var newName=companyName.replace(" ","+");
    var url="http://www.brightscope.com/autocomplete/search-box/company/?q=";
    url+=newName;
    url+="&limit=15&timestamp=1388104659571";
    return url;
}

function getjsonn(callback)
{

    var urlv=url();
    try
    {
    $.ajax({
        url:urlv,
        success: callback
        });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert("error");
    }       
}

function callback(result)
{
    document.getElementById('te').innerHTML=result[1].extra.id;
}








</script>
<title>The typeof operator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' onclick='url()' value='get url'/>
    <input type='button' onclick='getjsonn(callback)' value='get json'/>
    <p id="te">ddd</p>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your network tab say of the dev tools?

Comment: try adding an error handler

Comment: You're probably getting an error, meaning no success.

Comment: It shows a get request header and response hearder with details

Comment: because you don't call `getjsonn` anywhere in your code.

Comment: fyi, you can pass query string arguments as an object to the `data` argument of `$.ajax()`. that way jquery takes care of properly urlencoding it (right now e.g. a `&` in `newName` would break things)

Comment: Also quick tip you can condence that loop in your `url` fn to just `parts.split(" ").join("+")` or `parts.replace(" ", "+")`

Comment: Maksim Vi.  I called the function by clicking a button

Comment: you need to call it like `getjsonn(callback)`, not just `getjsonn()`

Comment: The url is correct, its http://www.brightscope.com/autocomplete/search-box/company/?q=ROCHESTER+REGIONAL+LIBRARY+COUNCIL&limit=15&timestamp=1388104659571&callback=?

Comment: Arun seem to be right... you've declared `callback` twice; once globally, and once locally.  Try removing the parameter from the function entirely if you want to call your global method, or make sure you're passing it correctly.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) violation if the URL is a different domain from your page.

Comment: Thanks  Arun P Johny , your answer helped me alot, now the callback function executes when I use IE browser, but firefox and crome dont no reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work normally. Please find chrome's error trace.

---

`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load http://www.brightscope.com/autocomplete/search-box/company/?q=ROCHESTER+REGIONAL+LIBRARY+COUNCIL&limit=15&timestamp=1388104659571. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://localhost'` is therefore not allowed access.

---

Please note for an ajax request to make calls to domains other than where you host your html and scripts, Those domains should allow and implement their services to be CORS (Cross Origin Resource sharing) way.